# batch file to open custom filetype

Tags: python, file, batch-file

I have a custom filetype (.photon) that is read by a python script which I generally run like this in a terminal:

```
py C:\Users\greym\Desktop\photon\photon.py C:\Users\greym\Desktop\photon\test.photon
```

the last argument is the file that is read by the python script how I make it so I can click on that file and it will run it through the python script

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows?

Comment: windows 10 pro 64 bit

Comment: why not use raw_input if python2 or input for python3

Comment: the file name needs to be used twice and making the user enter it twice is inefficient

Comment: user will input it once store it in a variable then use it 100 times. doesn't make difference.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [FTYPE](https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) and [ASSOC](https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) commands:

> ```
> ==> ftype /?
> Displays or modifies file types used in file extension associations
>
>   fileType          Specifies the file type to examine or change
>   openCommandString Specifies the open command to use when launching files
>                     of this type.
> …
>
> ==> assoc /?
> Displays or modifies file extension associations
>
> ASSOC [.ext[=[fileType]]]
>
>   .ext      Specifies the file extension to associate the file type with
>   fileType  Specifies the file type to associate with the file extension
> …
> ```

**Test** (please change paths to meet your circumstances):

Sample `photon.py` script reads a file in binary mode and prints its content to console:

```
import sys
if len( sys.argv) > 1:
    file_name = sys.argv[1]
else:
    file_name = 'D:\\test\\test.photon'    # if no file name supplied

with open( file_name, 'rb') as f:
    file_data = f.read()

print( file_data)

input( "Press Enter to continue...")
```

From elevated command prompt, run only once:

```
C:\Windows\system32> ftype photonfile=C:\Windows\py.exe -3 "D:\Python\photon.py" "%1" %*
photonfile=C:\Windows\py.exe -3 "D:\Python\photon.py" "%1" %*

C:\Windows\system32> assoc .photon=photonfile
.photon=photonfile

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Then, from any command prompt (or double click on a `.photon` file), run everywhen:

```
==> "D:\test\test.photon"
b'\xc4\x9b\xc5\xa1\xc4\x8d\xc5\x99\xc5\xbe\xc3\xbd\xc3\xa1\xc3\xad\xc3\xa9'
Press Enter to continue...

==>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input()` for python2 and `input()` for python3.

Store the output to a variable and use it whenever required. This will help you to use it by double clicking.